# One-directional sync of TFS (online) to SVN

Tags: svn, tfs

I have a very specific requirement. There is a TFS repository at visualstudio.com. There is an SVN repository on premise. At every successful build on TFS, a check-in should go into SVN.
However modifications on SVN shall not affect the TFS.

Is there any tool or service which can help me achieve this?

- [SvnTfsSync](http://ficusdev.com/SvnTfsSync/) only seems to support bi-directional sync
- [tfs2svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/) is rather a tool for migration, not sync
- [svnbridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) transforms SVN calls to TFS calls

What I have in mind is something like this: run something periodically on a machine, which checks the status of the given branch in TFS. If there is a new check-in, it downloads all the files, and does a commit to the SVN repository.

Where to look at automating this stuff, mainly watching the TFS on visualstudio.com from a command line tool/script?

Comment: If you simply want to commit, taking whatever version is on TFS as leading, then you could simply script svn.exe from the command line. Get latest from the svn server, copy the TFS sources over them, resolve all conflicts to local version and check back in.

Answer (score 1):

tfsexport.exe is the tool that I use. This is the link.  [TFSExport tool](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time.aspx)

This allows you to download files from the TFS Server without creating a workspace. It takes care of the read-only attribute and will remove the TFS binding if desired.